# Dockerized Application with React Frontend Keycloak Authentication Issuer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, keycloak, keycloak-js

i am developing a fullstack application where i run the already developed backend in docker containers with FastAPI and keycloak with docker.

The issue now is that the Authorization via token from the frontend in the backend fails. My initial thought is that the frontend accesses the keycloak via localhost:90 and the backend since it is running in docker is "host.docker.internal:90". When i now want to verify the token in the backend the issuer in the token is "localhost:90" is there any configuration to allow multiple issuers?

I have tried to find any configuration parameters which i didn´t found.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.